# Spring cloud config using VSTS git as config-repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, spring-cloud, ssh-keys, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use VSTS Git as my config repo.

Here's my application.yml (sensitive information hidden or removed)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: URL from VSTS
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          host-key-algorithm: ssh-rsa
          host-key: HOST KEY FROM VSTS
          search-paths: '{application}'
          private-key: |
                        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```
                       -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
         passphrase: SOME PASSPHRASE
```

I keep getting this error:

error: org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchRepositoryException: Cannot clone or checkout repository

Can anyone help me please?

EDIT-1:

- Was able to connect to VSTS Git using HTTPS + credential
- Configuration YAML files are on Git repo and can be fetched if using HTTPS.
- Tried both with and without "-" on the keys. No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug into spring cloud config server, the exact error is the host key is "**invalid key type**".

Then I realize the `hostKey` and `hostKeyAlgorithm` were specified.

As soon as I removed these 2 properties, VSTS Git could be connected.

The working application.yml looks like following:

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: URL from VSTS
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          search-paths: '{application}'
          private-key: |
                        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

`-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`